# Exponentiation in Scratch

Tags: performance, beginner, scratch

This was back when I was new to coding on Scratch (as in the case of coding projects entirely from scratch) around 7-8 months ago with [my Cookie Clicker in Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/814368636/) project that I made pretty much entirely myself. Now, what seemed to be a huge barrier for me was summing values so I could add a Buy 100 function for the in-game "buildings" which I never did. Now, right now, as you can see in [this screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbbK7.png), while I have code (that works) for it, I really feel like there's a way to optimize the code so that it's more readable. I understand what the code is doing, I'm just not sure that this is the most optimized version of the code. Is it true that this code can be improved, or is this truly  the most optimized the code can be?

---

Code in `[scratchblocks]` format:

---

```
[scratchblocks]
define pow(base)(power)
set [result v] to [1]
set [base v] to (base)
set [power v] to (round (power))
set [done v] to [0]
if <(power) < [0]> then
set [base v] to [((1) / (base))]
set [power v] to [-1(() *(round (power))]
end
repeat until <[done v] = [1]>
if <(([power v]) mod (2)) = [0]> then
set [result v] to (([result v]) * ([base v]))
change [power v] by (-1)
end
if <(([power v]) mod (2)) > [0]> then
set [done v] to [1]
end
if <<not <<[done v] = [1]>>>
set [base v] to (([base v]) * ([base v]))
set [power v] to (([power v]) / (2))
end
end
[/scratchblocks]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that your implementation is probably fine in terms of the method you're using, but this can be computed directly. Although scratch does not have an operator for an arbitrary-base power built in, they can pretty simply be converted to the existing `e^` operator by the relation b<sup>p</sup> = e<sup>p*ln(b)</sup> (or similar for the `10^` operator). In a scratch custom block that would look like this.

[image: pow function based on exponent base conversion]

This indeed ran much faster, about 13x as fast when I tested it on my machine. It also works for non-integer powers, although if you don't want this behavior you could round it like you currently are. A possible caveat to this approach is a slight loss of precision. For example, 2³² gives 4294967295.999997 compared to 4294967296 in the original, although this should usually not be an issue.

Edit: This method also won't work for a negative base due to the logarithm being undefined and giving NaN, although a base of 0 seemed to work fine. You could potentially check for this first by seeing if the power is even or odd, and and either cancel or pull out the negative respectively, then use the absolute value of the base. This won't work for negative bases and non-integer powers, which are undefined regardless.

Comment: So you're telling me that the original script, which can run on my device in under 1 millisecond, is 13x slower than your method? Wow. (for context I use a regular ol' Chromebook)

Comment: Scratch code runs pretty slowly, so there's a lot to gain by using built-in operations instead. But even outside of scratch there's often lots of room for speed improvement in places that we might think are close to optimal.